# Installing ubuntu (DUAL BOOT)

Tags: dual-boot

I HAVE ALREADY INSTALLED WINDOWS 8 AND WINDOWS XP ON MY c: AND d: DRIVES OF 50 GB EACH RESPECTIVELY. NOW i WANT TO INSTALL UBUNTU ON MY e: DRIVE OF CAPACITY 50 GB. HELP ME PLS WITH THE THINGS I NEED TO KNOW TO ACHIEVE THIS. TELL ME ABT THE PARTITIONING ALSO IN UBUNTU AS I DONT KNOW ABT ext4.

Comment: Ext4 is just a filesystem, like NTFS. I guess you don't actually _know_ them both :) If you installed Windows XP and Windows 8, installing Ubuntu will not be difficult for you.

Comment: THERE IS NO NEED TO YELL.  Also we can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to unlock Caps (as you type lowercase letters into uppercase, and vise-versa)

About Dual boot, you could do partitioning by GParted (in the terminal type `gparted` and enter).

About ext4, that is just a file system which is similiar to ext2-3 and is optimized for Linux. It is not supported by Windows, so in Windows it is shown as RAW.